# Error extracting heads from MODFLOW-USG binary with flopy

Tags: python, flopy

I'm trying to extract the simulated heads from a MODFLOW-USG binary head-save file, so I'm using flopy as follows:

```py
modelname = 'Model'

import flopy.utils.binaryfile as bf

# Create the headfile object
headobj = bf.HeadFile(modelname+'.hds')
head = headobj.get_data()
```

However, with the last line I got the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 17349 into shape (17338,8670)
```

The list of records is

```
(1, 1, 1., 1., b'           HEADU', 1, 8669, 1)
(1, 1, 1., 1., b'           HEADU', 8670, 17338, 2)
```

What is the correct way to load the heads from an existing MODFLOW-USG model with flopy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract heads from MODFLOW-USG binary output using flopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734703/extract-heads-from-modflow-usg-binary-output-using-flopy)

Comment: Have you tried using `get_alldata()` instead of `get_data`?

Answer (score 0):

If I pass `text='headu'` to the `HeadFile` constructor, then I can read the headsave file for a pretty simple MODFLOW-USG model:

```
headobj = bf.HeadFile(modelname+'.hds',text='headu')
head = headobj.get_data()
```

Comment: I have tried that and I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
hdobj = bf.HeadUFile(modelname+'.hds')
head = hdobj.get_data()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your contribution. While this answer might be correct, code-only answers are generally not preferred. Could you add at least a few lines of text explaining why this code solves the issue? Adding a link to the official documentation (of the `HeadUFile` method) would be useful as well.